# Nginx, http/2 и ошибка ERR_SPDY_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY

Tags: nginx

Подключаю в конфиге nginx-а поддержку протокола HTTP/2:

```
server {
    ...
    listen 433 ssl http2;
    ...
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate "....crtca";
    ssl_certificate_key "....key";
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MD5:!EXPORT:!EXP:!LOW:!SEED:!CAMELLIA:!IDEA:!PSK:!SRP:!SSLv2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
}
```

Делаю `reload`. Открываю страницу в Chrome вижу ошибку мол не удалось загрузить страницу, возникла ошибка: `ERR_SPDY_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY`. В FireFox вводишь URL в адресной строке, enter, и... совсем ничего, браузер даже не выводит никаких ошибок, просто открывается обратно начальная страница браузера. В IE сайт открывается без проблем.

Насколько я понимаю, ошибка говорит о том что мол канал недостаточно защищен. Кто знает что подразумевается под этим и как это исправить?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Гм. Прошу прощения, только задал вопрос, и уже сам нашел ответ: https://www.nginx.com/blog/early-alpha-patch-http2/#comment-2226129373

> It only works with ssl enabled as well. You need to start the cipher list like this too:
>   ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:...

**Добавлено:** 
Вот тут я привел пример правильной конфигурации секции ssl_* для корректной работы HTTP/2: https://intsystem.org/server/pereexal-na-https-vklyuchil-http2/